# Как придумать (или создать генератор) условия задачи о поиске пути на клетчатом поле?

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Имеется клетчатое поле, как в шахматах. В некоторых клетках есть спец. фишки, обозначающие бензозаправки. В одной клетке есть фишка-автомобиль. Он может двигаться по клеткам только вперед-назад, влево-вправо. У него есть бензобак размером 5. Это значит, что совершив переход из одной клетки в соседнюю, он теряет единицу бензина; при нуле бензина он дальше уже не сможет ехать.
Достигнув заправки, он восстанавливает уровень бензина, но не больше 5 (бензобак ограничен и с собой водитель канистру взять не догадывается).
Важно: между некоторыми соседними клетками есть стенки, через которые проехать нельзя.
Задача - обойти все заправки и вернуться в клетку, с которой начал путь.
Вопрос: как придумывать (каков алгоритм) такое расположение всех элементов, чтобы другому человеку было сложно решить, но решаемо?

Comment: Я бы, сначала, построил обыкновенный лабиринт, алгоритмы которого можно найти в сети. Потом, вычислил путь прохождения лабиринта. А потом, на этом пути, расставил заправки в нужных местах

Comment: Как и сказал @Дмытрык в интернете найдите алгоритмы генерации лабиринта. И например можно каждую 5 итерацию ставьте безозаправку, чтобы у игрока не было права на ошибку.